# choose row numbers to read from excel into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a shared spreadsheet that gets rows added to it everyday. I am creating a script that reads the spreadsheet into a dataframe `pd.read_excel(infile, sheet_name=0)` and checks for duplicate rows using `df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')`. The script is going to be be an installed package on multiple people's computer for them to use at any time and different people will want to check different rows. Is there a way to have whoever wants to use the script choose the range of rows they want to check? For example, if the spreadsheet has 100 rows, and someone wants to check for duplicate rows in rows 40-60, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, you want `.iloc`. For example, `my_df = df.iloc[40:60,:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept user inputs for the row bounds and then pass them to `iloc`:

```
import pandas as pd

start = int(input('Enter your starting row: '))
stop = int(input('Enter your ending row: '))

df_limited = df.iloc[start:stop].drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```